# How can I use session in service class for entity framework core global filters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have been trying to get session variable in service class set via DI in ASP.NET Core 2.0 app. I need to use "StruturePath" session variable for global filter in entity framework core and session variable is set via Login POST Action.
But it is throwing an exception on public string GetStructurePath().

Exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Session has not been configured for this application or request.'
```

I dislike the idea to use HttpContext in directly in DbContext.
Any suggestions would be helpful or any better approach to achieve this. 
Thanks

```
public class UserService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;

    public UserService(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        this.contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public string GetStructurePath()
    {
        return contextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Session?.GetString("StructurePath");
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Environment = env;


    }

    public IHostingEnvironment Environment { get; }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);

        // services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        //     options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddSingleton<IStringLocalizerFactory, EfStringLocalizerFactory>();


        //services.AddScoped(typeof(IEntityRepository<>), typeof(EntityRepository<>));
        //services.AddScoped<IMessageRepository, MessageRepository>();

        services.AddScoped<PersonService>();
        services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor,HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddTransient<UserService>();

        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        services.AddScoped<IDbFactory, DbFactory>();
        services.AddScoped<IDbInitializer, DbInitializer>();
        services.AddScoped<IDisposable, Disposable>();


        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

        services.AddScoped<CultureService>();


        services.AddLocalization(options =>
        {
            //options.ResourcesPath = "Resources";

        });

        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo(ApplicatonSettings.ItalianCulture),
            new CultureInfo(ApplicatonSettings.EnglishCulture),
        };

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(ApplicatonSettings.ItalianCulture);
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
            {
                //new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
                new CookieRequestCultureProvider()

            };
        });


        services.AddMvc()
            .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider()
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.SubFolder)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

        // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache.
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            //options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000);
            //options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        });

        //    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperProfile>());

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IDbInitializer dbInitializer)
    {

        ApplicatonSettings.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRequestLocalization();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        dbInitializer.Initialize();

        app.UseSession();



        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                 template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");///
        });
    }
}
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    private string _hierarchy;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, UserService userService)
        : base(options)
    {
        if(userService != null)
        {
            _hierarchy = userService.GetStructurePath();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //model
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_hierarchy) == false)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<PersonStruct>().HasQueryFilter(e => e.Hierarchy.StartsWith(_hierarchy));
        }
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: `OnModelCreating` will normally execute **only once**. What's exactly the point of all of this? Configuration shouldn't be in Session data, it should be in configuration files

Comment: As seen in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters the _tenantId is being used add where predicate filter for all queries in Blog entity, _tenantId will be different for every logged in user, I would like same to be used with variable value from session.

Comment: Anybody ideas ?

Comment: I have already tried using claims , but the issue here is OnModelCreating method is executed before user logs in therefore no claim values are set for logged in user and I have checked the OnModelCreating will execute only once and ef core global query filter isn't working as claim value is null.

Comment: Try to see what happens if you register your services with 
`AddScoped` instead of `AddTransient`. `AddScoped` will at least always match an HTTP request, while `AddTransient` won't, so your problem *could* be there. Not entirely sure that it will work though

Comment: Yes I tried using AddScoped but no luck.

Comment: I would add a log on `OnModelCreating` and see how many times that method is call when you navigate through the site. Then you can determine if it runs only once or multiple times and decide what's best